# Does compilation happens immediately after a script is parsed or is it deferred?

Tags: javascript

Consider a script included in a HTML page.

```
<script>
     function fn(){
      // code
      return new Function();
     }
</script>
```

1. When the above HTML page document is being rendered in my browser window, can I call it as *parsing the document*?
2. Does compilation also happens at the same time as when parsing a document? What exactly is the difference between these 2 processes?
3. Is the statement `return new Function()` also *parsed* and *compiled* at the same time as when `fn()` is parsed and compiled?

Comment: As an optimisation technique, it is deferred, but this doesn't really matter to you. Why do you want to know?

Comment: It is possible for a script to run before the HTML elements literally following it on the page have been loaded into the DOM. This is often a problem for beginners who find that the elements they try to manipulate are undefined. It is common practice to attach your javascript to the document's `load` event in order to make sure all DOM elements are in place before manipulating them. If you want to take advantage of this eagerness to run, though, I'm not sure. It would depend what you want to do.

Comment: @Paul: No no, i am not a beginner and I do know about where to include the script, window.onload, $( document ).ready().

Comment: 1. yes. 2. just after, once the script tag is parsed (inline) or loaded (external defer) or loaded and prior tags are loaded and parsed (external sync). 3. fn() is parsed with the script tag, but the Function()'s result wont exist until fn is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the above HTML page document is being rendered in my browser window, can I call it as parsing the document?

No. Your document is parsed from top to bottom. If the script is at the top, it'll be executed first. If it's at the end of the document, it'll be executed last.

> Does compilation also happens at the same time as when parsing a document? What exactly is the difference between these 2 processes?

Refer to my answer to your first question. Parsing a document involved constructing the DOM tree. A `script` tag is part of the DOM tree.

> Is the statement return new Function() also parsed and compiled at the same time as when fn() is parsed and compiled?

`return new Function()` will happen when you call `function fn()` in your code. If it's never called, then there will just be a stale reference to the function. You have to call `fn()` in order for it to return your new function, or whatever object you're going to return.

Comment: As per my understanding, any function won't be exceuted unless and until it is called(runtime).

Comment: @ShirgillAnsari yep exactly.

Comment: I had a look at the tool which you created. Believe me it's really amazing.

Comment: @ShirgillAnsari thanks a lot I'm glad it appears useful to you!

Answer (score 0):

1. It is possible for a script to run before the HTML elements literally following it on the page have been loaded into the DOM. This is often a problem for beginners who find that the elements they try to manipulate are undefined. It is common practice to attach your javascript to the document's load event in order to make sure all DOM elements are in place before manipulating them. If you want to take advantage of this eagerness to run, though, I'm not sure. It would depend what you want to do. It's a pretty safe bet though that if you define some javascript literally before you define some more javascript, perhaps later on the page, the first chunk of javascript will exist and be accessible.
2. Compilation does happen, but it's implementation-specific. Typically, it is compiled to bytecode at runtime. This means that it steps through the "text" as it's running and when it fully interprets a statement, it converts it to a quasi-assembly language that is easy for the browser's javascript engine to execute. It's a bit more complicated than that once you factor in things like the priority of function definitions, scope, etc, but that's the basic idea. One javascript engine may differ from another so it's not always going to be the same.
3. I am not sure.